# WooCommerce: Add product tabs in custom loop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tabs

I want to show the tabs of a product inside a custom product loop.

I'm using the following code to get a list of products:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => array('product'),
    'post__in'          => $results,
);
$products = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>
  
  <ul>
    <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>
      <li>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
              <div><?php the_title(); ?></div>
              <!-- Show Tabs of Product here -->
          </a>
      </li>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
  </ul>
  
<?php endif; ?>
```

Inside that list I want to show the tabs of each product.

But only the tabs with content. So of there is no ratings tab, I don't want to show that tab in the list. Basically the same way, the tabs work on every product page.

Unfortunately I'm not sure how to get tabs from a product ID.
Is there any way to do so?

I found a way based on the WooCommerce action.

So if I add the follwing code to the loop, it shows the tabs along with some other stuff:

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' ); ?>
```

That doesn't seem to be a good solution.
Isn't there a way to display only the tabs?

Comment: Which tab are you specifically looking for?

Comment: All of them ;) They are dynamic based on the product. So I couldn't tell which one I need.

Comment: According to the documentation, `do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' )` would give you, `woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs`, `woocommerce_upsell_display` and `woocommerce_output_related_products` tabs.

Comment: Yes I saw that. In my case there is some more stuff. Therefore I thought, that there is a better way maybe.

Comment: Is there a way to load a specific tab? And if yes, Is there a way to check if the tab has any content?

Comment: Can't tell you off the top of my head. I'll check and let you know if I find out.

Comment: **1/4** As @Ruvee already indicated, the [do_action](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/b19500728b4b292562afb65eb3a0c0f50d5859de/templates/content-single-product.php#L64-L72) will execute multiple callback functions, the default ones in WC and maybe even more depending on plugins/theme you're using that extend this hook with custom functions.

Comment: **2/4** For your question only `woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs` seems relevant. If we look at this further, we will come [to this](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/b19500728b4b292562afb65eb3a0c0f50d5859de/includes/wc-template-hooks.php#L130) 
and finally [this](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/0a857088f994def1aca6f3feb3e4a4af964b225f/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L1585-L1593).

Comment: **3/4** There you can see that via `wc_get_template()` the [tabs.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/b19500728b4b292562afb65eb3a0c0f50d5859de/templates/single-product/tabs/tabs.php) file is called. 
And on line [29](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/b19500728b4b292562afb65eb3a0c0f50d5859de/templates/single-product/tabs/tabs.php#L29), it determines which tabs.

Comment: **4/4** This refers to [this](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/b19500728b4b292562afb65eb3a0c0f50d5859de/includes/wc-template-hooks.php#L193) 
which in turn refers to [this](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/0a857088f994def1aca6f3feb3e4a4af964b225f/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L1820-L1861). 
and that part can be used as answer to your question